# italicize the subsubsection in latex

Tags: sectioning, formatting, article

How do i italicize the `\subsubsection{Subsubsection}`

```
1. section
1.1 subsection
1.1.1 subsubsection
```

I want the third line i.e. starting from `1.1.1 subsubsection` italicize.

Please help

Comment: Have you tried `\subsubsection{\textit{My subsubsection}}` ?

If it works, you could try :
    \let\mysubsubsection\subsubsection
    \renewcommand{\subsubsection}[1]{\textit{\mysubsubsection{#1}}}

Comment: thanku for yr suggestion. i got it. i was trying with some other way. \titleformat{\subsection}

       {\normalfont\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{12}{17}\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}

Comment: @JérômeDequeker - Your suggestion renders the subsubsection-level header text in bold-italics, not (plain) italics; furthermore, the subsubsection *number* (e.g., "1.1.1") will be rendered in bold, not italics.

Comment: Please tell us which document class you use, and whether or not you load packages -- such as `titlesec` and `sectsty` -- that are designed to modify the appearance of sectioning headers.

Comment: I am using the standard latex article only

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you're using one of the "standard" LaTeX document classes (`article`, `report`, `book`) or a document class that's based on one of the standard classes, you could load the `sectsty` package and issue the directive

```
\subsubsectionfont{\normalfont\itshape}
```

in the preamble.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\subsubsectionfont{\normalfont\itshape}
\begin{document}
\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsubsection{subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How can i put a dot after 1 in the section. meaning i want the section to be 1. Section

Comment: @roshni - Add the following instructions to the preamble: `\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}
   {\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}
   {\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}} 
\newcommand\section@cntformat{\thesection.\quad}
\makeatother`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a simple solution with `titlesec`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries\Large}{\thesection.}{0.5em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{\itshape}

\begin{document}

\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsubsection{subsubsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]